# How to use ArcGIS uniqueValues For two Fields in ArcGIS JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Using ArcGIS JavaScript API 4.24 and [uniqueValues](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-smartMapping-statistics-uniqueValues.html) from `esri/smartMapping/statistics/uniqueValues` I am able to get `Count` of all features in a `FeatureLayer` (fcLayer in this code)

In this example respond is based on `AppType` field from fcLayer

```
            uniqueValues({
                layer: fcLayer,
                field: "AppType",
            }).then(function(response) {
                let infos = response.uniqueValueInfos;
                infos.forEach(function(info) {
                    console.log("Application Type: ", info.value, " are: ", info.count);
                });
            });
```

[image]

Now Can you please let me know how I can robust this code in a way that I can group and query two fields `AppType` and `AppStat`  instead of `field: "AppType"` only?

I tried to use `sqlExpression` and `sqlWhere` instead of `field` option like

```
sqlExpression : "AppType = 'RD' AND AppStat = 'active'"
sqlWhere : "AppType = 'RD' AND AppStat = 'active'"
```

in the code like

```
        uniqueValues({
            layer: fcLayer,
            sqlExpression : "AppType = 'RD' AND AppStat = 'active'"
        }).then(function(response) {
```

or

```
        uniqueValues({
            layer: fcLayer,
            sqlWhere : "AppType = 'RD' AND AppStat = 'active'"
        }).then(function(response) {
```

But none of them returning any thing!

Comment: Both of your examples show using an `=` instead of a `:` in your JSON. 
 Have you tried: `sqlWhere: "AppType = 'RD' AND AppStat = 'active'"`.  It looks like you need to use `sqlWhere` instead of `sqlExpression`.

Comment: Oh thanks we_gis this is just a typo, either way! I am not getting anything back and I will update the code

Answer (score 0):

Using uniqueValues without field should give you this error:

```
"'layer' and 'field' or 'valueExpression' parameters are required"
```

You can see it in the console of the developer tool (open with F12 in most browsers).

If you use

```
uniqueValues({
  layer: fcLayer,
  field: "AppType",
  sqlWhere : "AppType = 'RD' AND AppStat = 'active'"
}).then(function(response) {
```

it should work.